# When doing an area between curves, what is a quick way to know which is the top and bottom & left and right graph?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, graphing-functions, area

I'm taking calculus and we're up to areas between curves. Thing is that unless I do a table of values and graph, or I'm given an easy transformation, its really hard to figure out which graph is the top and bottom so I can do

$A=\int_a^b \! F_{top} - F_{bottom} \, \textrm{d}x$ or $A=\int_c^d \! F_{right} - F_{left} \, \textrm{d}x$

Also, what's a quick way of determining a problem in which I'll have to add two integrals and when I only need to solve one?

Comment: May be, anylizing the integrand first would help. Is it always positive, always negative ? Does the integrand show a root between the bounds ? Does this clarify something ? If not, just post and I shall try to be better in mpy explanations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no quicker way, I think, than graphing the curves as accurately as possible, finding the points of intersection around the area enclosed...and see the limits /extreme point positions for $x,y$.

Comment: what should I take the limit of?

Comment: The curves cut at $ x_{left}, y_{bottom}$ and $  x_{right},y_{top}$ and so on..The 2 points supply 4 required coordinates.